# Got OutOfMemory when run Spark MLlib kmeans

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I always got OutOfMemory error when I ran Spark Kmeans on big data set. The training set about 250GB, I have 10 nodes spark cluster each machine with 16 cpus and 150G memory. I give the job 100GB memory on each node and 50 cpus totally. I set the cluster center is 100 and iteration is 5. But I got OutOfMemory when the code was running on the following line:

```
val model = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)
```

Is there any parameter I can tune to fix the problem please.

If I set smaller cluster center number or iteration number it would be ok.

My Code as following:

```
val originalData = sc.textFile("hdfs://host/input.txt").cache()
val tupleData = originalData.map { x => (x.split(":")(0),x.split(":")(1)) }
val parsedData = tupleData.map { x => x._1 }.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(',').map(_.toDouble)))

val model = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations, 1, initializationMode = KMeans.RANDOM)
val resultRdd = tupleData.map { p => (model.predict(Vectors.dense(p._1.split(',').map(_.toDouble))),p._2)}
resultRdd.sortByKey(true, 1).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://host/output.txt")
```

My input format as following:

```
0.0,0.0,91.8,21.67,0.0 ... (the element number is 100K)
1.1,1.08,19.8,0.0,0.0 ... 
0.0,0.08,19.8,0.0,0.0 ...
...
The rows number is 600K.
```

The Exception I got as following:

```
scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ShuffleMapStage 42 (MapPartitionsRDD[49] at map at KmeansTest.scala:47), which has no missing parents
Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1785)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1188)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Spark's Kmeans implementation use `K_MEANS_PARALLEL` initialization mode. Part of this mode run on the driver machine and can be extremely slow / cause OOM on the driver, depending on your data.

Try switching to `RANDOM` initialization mode.

```
val model = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations, 1, initializationMode = KMeans.RANDOM)
```

Another thing to try is to increase your driver memory when you submit your application. For example, use the following command to set driver memory to 4G

```
spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.memory=4g" ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It fixed my problem. Could I ask one more question please: why I got different result each time even though I always set my numCluster=10, and numIteration=5.

Comment: K-means is an optimizing algorithm, so different initial centroids (due to random initialization) can lead to different clustering.

Comment: Thank you, Actually I still meeting the OutOfMemory exception, I updated my question with more info please.

Comment: Try increasing your driver memory, see my updated answer.

Comment: thank you so so much, it works! Actually I set Master total memory is 30g, I thought the client would treat it as drive memory. Just knew I must set spark.driver.memory. Embarrassing, I just knew this config even though I have used Spark for years.